# postgres query with json

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, psql

I have JSON in a column named `payload`:

```
"status":"E",
"statusText":"{\"status\":\"INVALID\",\"description\":\"Данные некорректны\}",
"errorCode":"smev_error"
```

I know how to get only `statusText`:

```
SELECT payload::json->>'statusText' FROM table_name;
```

It will show me

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------------------------------
?column? | {"status":"INVALID","description":"Данные некорректны"}
```

I need to get only `description`. I found out construction with `#>` can resolve my trouble but I don't really know how to build a query with that. So I want to get something like that:

```
?column? | {"Данные некорректны"}
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Just cast once again to have the status text as `json` as well.

```
SELECT (payload::json->>'statusText')::json->>'description' AS description
       FROM table_name;
```

Comment: it works perfect! Thank you so much!